# How do I handle a boolean HTML attribute in a Handlebars partial?

Tags: handlebars.js

I'm writing a fun little project to build up my HTML/JS skills. I'm using Handlebars to render some forms, and I hit something I can't seem to get around.

I've registered this as a partial template named 'checkbox':

```
<label>
<input 
   type="checkbox" 
   id="{{id}}" 
   name="{{id}}" 
   value="true">
{{labelText}}
</label>
```

That did me well when I was making forms to add data, but now I'm making forms to *edit* data, so I want to make the checkbox checked if the current item already is checked. I can't figure out how to make this work.

The first thing I tried was something like this:

```
<label>
<input 
   type="checkbox" 
   id="{{id}}" 
   name="{{id}}" 
   value="true"
   checked="{{isChecked}}">
{{labelText}}
</label>
```

But if I pass that values like `isChecked=true` I get a checked box every time, because I guess for that kind of attribute in HTML being present at all means 'true'. OK.

So I tried using the if helper:

```
<input 
   type="checkbox" 
   id="{{id}}" 
   name="{{id}}" 
   value="true"
   {{#if isChecked}}checked{{/if}}>
{{labelText}}
```

This *sort of* works. If I omit the `isChecked` property entirely, the box is unchecked. If I hard-code a `true` or `false` value like this, it works:

```
{{> checkbox id="test" labelText="test" isChecked=true }}
```

But I can't seem to get what I want with a value there. For example, if I try:

```
{{> checkbox id="test" labelText="test" isChecked="{{someCondition}}" }}
```

It seems like the condition isn't properly being resolved because I always get the attribute in that case.

What am I missing? I feel like there should be a way to do this, but I'm running out of tricks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot put an expression inside of another expression:

```
{{> checkbox id="test" labelText="test" isChecked="{{someCondition}}" }}
```

From examples you wrote I assume the problem you are having is related to how you pass the context - `id` and `labelText` are hardcoded while `isChecked` is expected to be a variable of some sort. In reality all those should be variables. Consider the following example - HTML:

```
<div id="content"></div>

<script id="parent-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  {{#each checkboxes}}
    {{> checkbox this }}<br>
  {{/each}}
</script>

<script id="partial-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <input 
    type="checkbox" 
    id="{{id}}" 
    name="{{id}}" 
    value="true"
    {{#if isChecked}}checked{{/if}}>
  {{labelText}}
</script>
```

JS:

```
var parentTemplate = Handlebars.compile($("#parent-template").html());

Handlebars.registerPartial({
  checkbox: Handlebars.compile($("#partial-template").html())
});

$('#content').html(parentTemplate(
  {checkboxes: [
    {id: 1, labelText: "test 1", isChecked: true},
    {id: 2, labelText: "test 2", isChecked: false},
  ]}
));
```

Comment: Huh, OK. Didn't want my context to be quite that tied to view details but it is what it is. I'm going to experiment with that and using a helper instead.

Comment: Yep, OK, even with Helpers I have to write it like you indicated. It is what it is!